# Setting Response to session

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee, response, portlet

Setting response in session

```
    @ResourceMapping("SomeValue")
    public void getSites(ResourceRequest request, ResourceResponse response) {
    try {
            String _emailAddress = UserUtils.getEmailAddress(request);
 //Service call here                
 // Need not call the service if the user is in session.
            render(sitesXML, MediaType.TEXT_XML.toString(),response);
     }catch{
        ...}
  ...
  ...
```

return MYVALUE;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What framework are you using??
If you are using a framework, surely you can have a reference of the session object within the getSites() method. Try getting a session object from your framework.

Your code may look like as below,

```
String sitesXML="";
if(sessionObject.get("sitesXmlKey") == null){
sitesXML = (String) sitesService.getSitesForUser(String.class,_emailAddress);
sessionObject.put("sitesXMLKey",sitesXML);
}else{
sitesXML = (String)sessionObject.get("sitesXmlKey");
}
```